# Nouveau drivers does not refresh screen & nvidia drivers are crazy on power consumtion

Tags: ubuntu, multiple-monitors, nvidia-graphics-card, nouveau

I want to use my laptop out doors and that is not possible because somehow the battery life is so short (2 hours at max).

1. I investigated everything possible using `powertop`, `tlp` & other unfamiliar software.
2. NVIDIA was suspicious, although I turned it off using `prime-select intel` it remained working (probably because it is a firmware and it is always launched). so i had to purge it. The power consumption decreased from 17-18 Watt/hour till 6 Watt/hour.
3. I decreased the power consumption further more by decreasing cpu max performance & turbo boost (setting it to 30% and noturbo to 1) (files are in `/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo` & `/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/max_perf_pct`)
4. I Installed Nouveau drivers and tried to work with it but it simply does not work out of the box, not even from the live usb; when i connect the cable, both screens are on but the external screen does not refresh the frame ever, literally the mouse moves normally but to refresh the frame, i need to edit the FPS of the external monitor as in the following picture (it updates only once i change the value)
   [image]
5. I inspected that installing Nouveau drivers using Ubuntu Software & Updates might be out dated so i used `sudo apt install xserver-xorg-video-nouveau` but instead, the external screen screen was not detected and the laptop screen turned black.

Comment: I'd go for disabling the dedicated gpu, go for the Intel's built-in.

Comment: please, what do you mean by Intel's built in? do you mean that Intel works without installing any drivers for it?

Comment: What CPU does your laptop have precisely?  https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/intel-hd-graphics-comparison

Comment: Very sorry for the late reply; GTX 1050Ti

Comment: Wrong answer.  That is a GPU, not a CPU.

Comment: Extremely sorry :D, i really have stigmatism. Intel i7 8750H

Comment: check this: https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/134906/intel-core-i7-8750h-processor-9m-cache-up-to-4-10-ghz.html   Your processor contains an UHD 630 graphics card.  That means you can do almost everything with your laptop without using the NVidia.  Except for really heavy gaming or CUDA.

Comment: Thank you; please let me know, how would i uninstall Nouveau if i installed it using Ubuntu Software & Updates? i tried `apt purge` for nouveau but it still appear in the system and Ubuntu Software & Updates that it is installed and it works when i connect an external HDMI to the laptop.

Comment: I would blacklist both nouveau and nvidia.  No need to uninstall, just reboot.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply @GerardH.Pille; i tried this link but it never showed any results. the same power used and the external screen worked.

link: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-disable-blacklist-nouveau-nvidia-driver-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux

Comment: In that link, only nouveau gets blacklisted.